# Concatenate vectors and preserve columns headers in R

Tags: r

I'm new to this community and I hope my question is not redundant. I have been looking around in the web but I couldn't get my head around this problem:

I want to read several .csv files in R, extract some information and concatenate the extracted information in a new vector while preserving the columns headers. This is the code I have:

```
files_dir <- "C:/Users/blabla"
files_name = list.files(path = files_dir, pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names     = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE, include.dirs = FALSE, no.. = FALSE)
N <- length(files_name)
X <- matrix(data = NA, nrow =0, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)

for (i in 1:N){
  X1 <- read.csv(paste(files_dir,files_name[i],sep=""),sep=";",header=TRUE)
  X <- rbind(X, cbind(X1$label_1, X1$label_2, X1$label_3.))}
```

I basically would like to read a sequence of files, extract the information in label_1, label_2 and label_3 of each file and concatenate (or, to say, append) it in the vector X.
At the end I'd like to have something like this:

> names(X)

```
[1]"label_1" "label_2" "label_3"
```

Thanks in advance for the help.
G.

Comment: Is the problem that your result doesn't have the right names?  Or that what you're trying isn't working at all (or is too slow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
X <- read.csv(paste(files_dir,files_name[1],sep=""),sep=";",header=TRUE)[,c("label_1","label_2","label_3")]

for (i in 2:N){
  X1 <- read.csv(paste(files_dir,files_name[i],sep=""),sep=";",header=TRUE)[,c("label_1","label_2","label_3")]
  X <- rbind(X, X1)
}
```

You shouldn't need the cbind commands

Comment: Thank you Vincent! I actually need to discard some columns from the original file, that's why when I concatenate the new information in X, I take only some fields from X1, e.g., X1$TIMESTAMP. I gould get around this by just doing, after the for loop:
X<-data.frame(X)
colnames(X) <- c("name1","name2","Name3")

Maybe is not the most efficient way, but it fixed the problem